# Remover espaço em branco do csv

Tags: php, csv

Estou com um problema quando o usuário sobe um arquivo .CSV. Se em alguns dos campos tiver um espaço em branco no final eu não consigo removê-lo de nenhuma forma.

Por exemplo: "lucas@gmail.com "

Já tentei utilizar `trim()`, `rtrim()` e não funciona
Quando eu utilizo `str_replace()` ele remove todos os espaços que tenha no meio da string mas essa do final não remove.

Já procurei em todo lugar e não acho uma solução. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Código conforme solicitado:

```
foreach($column_headers as $key => $value)
{
     $result[$new_row][$value] = trim($data[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Coloca o trecho do código, fica mais fácil para entender o problema.

Comment: @MarcosMarques editei a pergunta com o código conforme solicitado. Valeu

Comment: Já considerou a tabela ascii no str_replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a única forma que eu consegui de retirar esse espaço em branco foi assim:

```
$email = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $email);
```

pelo que vi, esse `'/[[:^print:]]/'` retira caracteres não imprimíveis.